# postman - special characters in header request throws error

Tags: postman

Trying to post characters from other languages in the Request Header. For example some Italian characters for a user name.

Receiving Error:

> Error while sending request: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader on 'XMLHttpRequest': âçéÿ€èëïîôœæâà is not a valid HTTP header field value.

This header works in other tools, but we are trying to switch over to postman, does anyone know of a way to get around this in postman?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like you should contact the creators of postman (btw I really like postman)

Comment: Start off the question with a question.

Answer (score 5):

In my case there was a white space at the end of the header name which caused the problem. Removing it resolved the issue.

Comment: I can't believe it, this happend to me too and burnt a hafty amount of time... I wonder why they don't address this in Postman... a simple trim to whitespaces... -_- Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

The error itself tell the description.That it's not a valid Header.Maybe some typo mistakes in the Header values.Please check it.

Also, I'd suggest copy and paste the header from the tool which you mentioning as working.

Answer (score 0):

This problem mainly causing by typo , You can check do you have any space between your token, token can not contain any space beside of token type :

For example : Barear: Token
The above example will cause a header request error :

"Barear: Tok en" //you can see there is a space there.